# Why does my iterator class housed inside my singly linked list give me a segmentation fault in c++?

Tags: c++, list, iterator, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

all.

I'm currently working on my singly linked list and hit a road block with my iterator class. This is so far what I have and I'll start with the node, then the singly linked list, then the iterator it self.

My nodes look like this currently. I apologize in advance for "syntax errors" shown in my code below. I can't properly indent with out compromising the code text in this website. I'm still getting use to how stackoverflow works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
class SingleNode 
{
private:
     int key_;
     SingleNode * next_;
public:
      SingleNode(int key, SingleNode * next = NULL)
        : key_(key), next_(next)
     {
     }

     void set_key(int key)
     {
        key_ = key;
     }

     int get_key() const
     {
        return key_;
     }

     int & get_key()
     {
        return key_;
     }

     SingleNode * get_next() const
     {
        return next_;
     }

     SingleNode * set_next(SingleNode * next)
     {
        next_ = next;
     }
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & cout, const SingleNode & node)
{
    cout << "< " << ' ' << &node << ' '
         << "key: " << node.get_key() << ' '
         << "next: " << node.get_next() << '>';
     return cout;
}
```

Now for my SinglyLinked list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include "SingleNode.h"

class SingleNode;

class SingleLinked
{
private:
    SingleNode * phead_;
public:
    SingleLinked()
       : phead_(NULL)
    {
    }

    class iterator
    {
        friend class SingleLinked;

    private:
        SingleNode * p;

        iterator(SingleNode * phead)
               : p(phead)
        {
        }

    public:
        iterator()
           : p(NULL)
        {
        }

        int & operator*()
        {
            return p->get_key();
        }

        int & operator++()
        {
            p = p->get_next();
        }
    };

    iterator begin() const
    {
        return iterator(phead_);
    }

    SingleNode * get_phead() const
    {
        return phead_;
    }

    SingleNode * insert_head(int key)
    {
         phead_ = new SingleNode(key, phead_);
    }

    SingleNode * insert_tail(int key)
    {
        SingleNode * p = new SingleNode(key, NULL);
        SingleNode * r = p;
        SingleNode * q = phead_;

        while (q->get_next() != NULL)
        {
            q = q->get_next();
        }
        q->set_next(r);
    }

    void delete_head()
    {
        SingleNode * p = phead_;
        phead_ = p->get_next();
    }

    void delete_tail()
    {
         SingleNode * p = phead_;
         while (p->get_next() != NULL)
         {
            p = p->get_next();
         }

         SingleNode * r = phead_;
         while (r->get_next() != p)
         {
            r = r->get_next();
         }

         r->set_next(NULL);
    }

    void print()
    {
        while (phead_ != NULL)
        {
           std::cout << *phead_ << std::endl;
           phead_ = phead_->get_next();
        }
    }
};
```

The idea is this, I want to use the SingleLinked class as a friend class to the iterator. That way, once the SingleLinked class is initialized in the main, it automatically constructs the iterator inside of it. This runs into some problems as soon as I start using the begins method.

This is the main so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SingleLinked.h"

int main()
{
     SingleLinked list;
     list.insert_head(1);
     list.insert_tail(2);

     typename SingleLinked::iterator p = list.begin();
     std::cout << *p << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Once I try to cout that iterator p, it shows a segmentation fault in the console. What is going inside my SingleLinked class itself that is causing this?

Comment: (A) The code you posted doesn't compile due to a missing `;`.  (B) You should really turn on and pay attention to compiler warnings.  You are missing return statements in several functions declared to return a value.  That is the source of your crash.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I'd beg to differ, bud.

Comment: @KennethMcAusland, in what way do you differ?

Comment: @MilesBudnek If we are talking about just the List itself, it compiles on my g++ compiler just fine. Don't know what compiler you're using but outside of that missing ; thing you were referring to.... and I hope to god you didn't just copy and past this all the way through... it compiles.

Comment: @MilesBudnek The only thing that causes a crash is that segmentation faul from the iterator class itself though. Don't know what's going on with it.

Comment: @KennethMcAusland, use the compiler flag `-Wall`. You might notice a few more things.

Comment: @RSahu Cin-wall? I heard about this, exactly how in the main would I use that? Like say std::cin-Wall >> *p
??

Comment: @KennethMcAusland, you would use that as a compiler flag, as in `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall` or `g++ -std=c++14 -Wall`

Comment: Here are the [errors and warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b81f11c81e60487) I observe when compiling the code you posted here.  After fixing the missing `;` and all of the missing return values, the [program compiles and runs](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/affca937dceefb90) without issue.

Comment: @MilesBudnek The missing `;` was edited in 16 minutes ago.

Comment: @JaMiT Ah, didn't notice the edit.  The rest is still valid though.

Comment: @JaMiT That will depend on your compiler and compiler options.  The program's behavior is undefined, and at least for GCC 9.2 using -O2, it [crashes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/990ae1e661116d31) with the missing return values.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Hmm... looks like I did indeed have optimizations off. So the crash comes when warnings are off and optimizations are on.

Comment: I really don't have any words on this one guys. I just re did this whole thing and for some reason... without doing any editing... it works. Shrugs.

Comment: thanks for the help anyway guys. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)